# How to refresh div without duplicating it/losing its content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

i'm trying to make a world map (jvectormap) with information about payments per country in my laravel project. On the map i have installed a date range picker plugin to filter the date range of the data used by the map.

*The thing i'm trying is to refresh the div with the jvectormap using jquery .load():*

```
$("#vmap").load(location.href + " #vmap");
```

The problem with this is that the it duplicates my vmap div and uses it as a child deleting all my other child elements, so when it refreshes, theres no map.

*html:*

```
<div id="vmap" style="height: 250px; width: 100%;"><div id="vmap" style="height: 250px; width: 100%;"></div></div>
```

while it was like this before the refresh:

```
    <div id="vmap" style="height: 250px; width: 100%;"><div class="jvectormap-container" style="background-color: transparent;"><svg width="365.406" height="250"><defs></defs><g transform="scale(0.4060066666666667) translate(0, 87.52356258001963)"><path d="M651.84,230.21l-0.6,-2.0l-1.36,-1.71l-2.31,-0.11l-0.41,0.48l0.2,0.94l-0.53,0.99l-0.72,-0.36l-0.68,0.35l-1.2,-0.36l-0.37,-2.0l-0.81,-1.86l0.39,-1.46l-0.22,-0.47l-

...

 fill-opacity="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" class="jvectormap-region jvectormap-element"></path></g><g></g><g></g><g></g></svg><div class="jvectormap-zoomin">+</div><div class="jvectormap-zoomout">−</div><div class="jvectormap-legend-cnt jvectormap-legend-cnt-h"><div class="jvectormap-legend"><div class="jvectormap-legend-inner"><div style="clear: both;"></div></div></div></div><div class="jvectormap-legend-cnt jvectormap-legend-cnt-v"></div></div></div>
```

Code map:

```
 var landcodes = {"BD": "Bangladesh", "BE": "Belgium", "BF": "Burkina Faso", "BG": "Bulgaria", "BA": "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "BB": "Barbados", "WF": "Wallis and Futuna", "BL": "Saint Barthelemy", "BM": "Bermuda", "BN": "Brunei", "BO": "Bolivia", "BH": "Bahrain", "BI": "Burundi", "BJ": "Benin", "BT": "Bhutan", "JM": "Jamaica", "BV": "Bouvet Island", "BW": "Botswana", "WS": "Samoa", "BQ": "Bonaire, Saint Eustatius and Saba ", "BR": "Brazil", "BS": "Bahamas", "JE": "Jersey", "BY": "Belarus", "BZ": "Belize", "RU": "Russia", "RW": "Rwanda", "RS": "Serbia", "TL": "East Timor", "RE": "Reunion", "TM": "Turkmenistan", "TJ": "Tajikistan", "RO": "Romania", "TK": "Tokelau", "GW": "Guinea-Bissau", "GU": "Guam", "GT": "Guatemala", "GS": "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "GR": "Greece", "GQ": "Equatorial Guinea", "GP": "Guadeloupe", "JP": "Japan", "GY": "Guyana", "GG": "Guernsey", "GF": "French Guiana", "GE": "Georgia", "GD": "Grenada", "GB": "United Kingdom", "GA": "Gabon", "SV": "El Salvador", "GN": "Guinea", "GM": "Gambia", "GL": "Greenland", "GI": "Gibraltar", "GH": "Ghana", "OM": "Oman", "TN": "Tunisia", "JO": "Jordan", "HR": "Croatia", "HT": "Haiti", "HU": "Hungary", "HK": "Hong Kong", "HN": "Honduras", "HM": "Heard Island and McDonald Islands", "VE": "Venezuela", "PR": "Puerto Rico", "PS": "Palestinian Territory", "PW": "Palau", "PT": "Portugal", "SJ": "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "PY": "Paraguay", "IQ": "Iraq", "PA": "Panama", "PF": "French Polynesia", "PG": "Papua New Guinea", "PE": "Peru", "PK": "Pakistan", "PH": "Philippines", "PN": "Pitcairn", "PL": "Poland", "PM": "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "ZM": "Zambia", "EH": "Western Sahara", "EE": "Estonia", "EG": "Egypt", "ZA": "South Africa", "EC": "Ecuador", "IT": "Italy", "VN": "Vietnam", "SB": "Solomon Islands", "ET": "Ethiopia", "SO": "Somalia", "ZW": "Zimbabwe", "SA": "Saudi Arabia", "ES": "Spain", "ER": "Eritrea", "ME": "Montenegro", "MD": "Moldova", "MG": "Madagascar", "MF": "Saint Martin", "MA": "Morocco", "MC": "Monaco", "UZ": "Uzbekistan", "MM": "Myanmar", "ML": "Mali", "MO": "Macao", "MN": "Mongolia", "MH": "Marshall Islands", "MK": "Macedonia", "MU": "Mauritius", "MT": "Malta", "MW": "Malawi", "MV": "Maldives", "MQ": "Martinique", "MP": "Northern Mariana Islands", "MS": "Montserrat", "MR": "Mauritania", "IM": "Isle of Man", "UG": "Uganda", "TZ": "Tanzania", "MY": "Malaysia", "MX": "Mexico", "IL": "Israel", "FR": "France", "IO": "British Indian Ocean Territory", "SH": "Saint Helena", "FI": "Finland", "FJ": "Fiji", "FK": "Falkland Islands", "FM": "Micronesia", "FO": "Faroe Islands", "NI": "Nicaragua", "NL": "Netherlands", "NO": "Norway", "NA": "Namibia", "VU": "Vanuatu", "NC": "New Caledonia", "NE": "Niger", "NF": "Norfolk Island", "NG": "Nigeria", "NZ": "New Zealand", "NP": "Nepal", "NR": "Nauru", "NU": "Niue", "CK": "Cook Islands", "XK": "Kosovo", "CI": "Ivory Coast", "CH": "Switzerland", "CO": "Colombia", "CN": "China", "CM": "Cameroon", "CL": "Chile", "CC": "Cocos Islands", "CA": "Canada", "CG": "Republic of the Congo", "CF": "Central African Republic", "CD": "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "CZ": "Czech Republic", "CY": "Cyprus", "CX": "Christmas Island", "CR": "Costa Rica", "CW": "Curacao", "CV": "Cape Verde", "CU": "Cuba", "SZ": "Swaziland", "SY": "Syria", "SX": "Sint Maarten", "KG": "Kyrgyzstan", "KE": "Kenya", "SS": "South Sudan", "SR": "Suriname", "KI": "Kiribati", "KH": "Cambodia", "KN": "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "KM": "Comoros", "ST": "Sao Tome and Principe", "SK": "Slovakia", "KR": "South Korea", "SI": "Slovenia", "KP": "North Korea", "KW": "Kuwait", "SN": "Senegal", "SM": "San Marino", "SL": "Sierra Leone", "SC": "Seychelles", "KZ": "Kazakhstan", "KY": "Cayman Islands", "SG": "Singapore", "SE": "Sweden", "SD": "Sudan", "DO": "Dominican Republic", "DM": "Dominica", "DJ": "Djibouti", "DK": "Denmark", "VG": "British Virgin Islands", "DE": "Germany", "YE": "Yemen", "DZ": "Algeria", "US": "United States", "UY": "Uruguay", "YT": "Mayotte", "UM": "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "LB": "Lebanon", "LC": "Saint Lucia", "LA": "Laos", "TV": "Tuvalu", "TW": "Taiwan", "TT": "Trinidad and Tobago", "TR": "Turkey", "LK": "Sri Lanka", "LI": "Liechtenstein", "LV": "Latvia", "TO": "Tonga", "LT": "Lithuania", "LU": "Luxembourg", "LR": "Liberia", "LS": "Lesotho", "TH": "Thailand", "TF": "French Southern Territories", "TG": "Togo", "TD": "Chad", "TC": "Turks and Caicos Islands", "LY": "Libya", "VA": "Vatican", "VC": "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "AE": "United Arab Emirates", "AD": "Andorra", "AG": "Antigua and Barbuda", "AF": "Afghanistan", "AI": "Anguilla", "VI": "U.S. Virgin Islands", "IS": "Iceland", "IR": "Iran", "AM": "Armenia", "AL": "Albania", "AO": "Angola", "AQ": "Antarctica", "AS": "American Samoa", "AR": "Argentina", "AU": "Australia", "AT": "Austria", "AW": "Aruba", "IN": "India", "AX": "Aland Islands", "AZ": "Azerbaijan", "IE": "Ireland", "ID": "Indonesia", "UA": "Ukraine", "QA": "Qatar", "MZ": "Mozambique"};


var payments =  {
    "AF": 0,
    "AL": 0,
    "DZ": 0,
    "AO": 0,
    "AG": 0,
    "AR": 0,
    "AM": 0,
    "AU": 0,
    "AT": 0,
    "AZ": 0,
    "BS": 0,
    "BH": 0,
    "BD": 0,
    "BB": 0,
    "BY": 0,
    "BE": 3,
    "BZ": 0,
    "BJ": 0,
    "BT": 0,
    "BO": 0,
    "BA": 0,
    "BW": 0,
    "BR": 0,
    "BN": 0,
    "BG": 0,
    "BF": 0,
    "BI": 0,
    "KH": 0,
    "CM": 0,
    "CA": 0,
    "CV": 0,
    "CF": 0,
    "TD": 0,
    "CL": 0,
    "CN": 0,
    "CO": 0,
    "CU": 0,
    "KM": 0,
    "CD": 0,
    "CG": 0,
    "CR": 0,
    "CI": 0,
    "HR": 0,
    "CY": 0,
    "CZ": 0,
    "DK": 0,
    "DJ": 0,
    "DM": 0,
    "DO": 0,
    "EC": 0,
    "EG": 0,
    "EH": 0,
    "SV": 0,
    "GQ": 0,
    "ER": 0,
    "EE": 0,
    "ET": 0,
    "FJ": 0,
    "FI": 0,
    "FK": 0,
    "FR": 30,
    "GA": 0,
    "GM": 0,
    "GL": 0,
    "GE": 0,
    "DE": 6,
    "GH": 0,
    "GR": 0,
    "GD": 0,
    "GT": 0,
    "GN": 0,
    "GW": 0,
    "GY": 0,
    "HT": 0,
    "HN": 0,
    "HK": 0,
    "HU": 0,
    "IS": 0,
    "IN": 0,
    "ID": 0,
    "IR": 0,
    "IQ": 0,
    "IE": 0,
    "IL": 0,
    "IT": 0,
    "JM": 0,
    "JP": 0,
    "JO": 0,
    "KZ": 0,
    "KE": 0,
    "KI": 0,
    "KR": 0,
    "UNDEFINED": 0,
    "KW": 0,
    "KG": 0,
    "LA": 0,
    "LV": 0,
    "LB": 0,
    "LS": 0,
    "LR": 0,
    "LY": 0,
    "LT": 0,
    "LU": 0,
    "MK": 0,
    "MG": 0,
    "MW": 0,
    "MY": 0,
    "MV": 0,
    "ML": 0,
    "MT": 0,
    "MR": 0,
    "MU": 0,
    "MX": 0,
    "MD": 0,
    "MN": 0,
    "ME": 0,
    "MA": 0,
    "MZ": 0,
    "MM": 0,
    "NC": 0,
    "NA": 0,
    "NP": 0,
    "NL": 0,
    "NZ": 0,
    "NI": 0,
    "NE": 0,
    "NG": 0,
    "NO": 0,
    "OM": 0,
    "PK": 0,
    "PR": 0,
    "PA": 0,
    "PG": 0,
    "PY": 0,
    "PE": 0,
    "PH": 0,
    "PL": 0,
    "PT": 0,
    "QA": 0,
    "RO": 0,
    "RU": 0,
    "RW": 0,
    "WS": 0,
    "ST": 0,
    "SA": 0,
    "SN": 0,
    "RS": 0,
    "SC": 0,
    "SL": 0,
    "SG": 0,
    "SK": 0,
    "SI": 0,
    "SB": 0,
    "ZA": 0,
    "ES": 0,
    "LK": 0,
    "KN": 0,
    "KP": 0,
    "LC": 0,
    "VC": 0,
    "SD": 0,
    "SR": 0,
    "SZ": 0,
    "SE": 0,
    "SO": 0,
    "SS": 0,
    "CH": 0,
    "SY": 0,
    "TW": 0,
    "TJ": 0,
    "TZ": 0,
    "TF": 0,
    "TH": 0,
    "TL": 0,
    "TG": 0,
    "TO": 0,
    "TT": 0,
    "TN": 0,
    "TR": 0,
    "TM": 0,
    "UG": 0,
    "UA": 0,
    "AE": 0,
    "GB": 0,
    "US": 0,
    "UY": 0,
    "UZ": 0,
    "VU": 0,
    "VE": 0,
    "VN": 0,
    "XK": 0,
    "XS": 0,
    "YE": 0,
    "ZM": 0,
    "ZW": 0
};


 var locatie = @json($locatie);

 var loc = [];
 var land = [];
 var landcount = [];


 function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
  return Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key] === value);
}

for (i = 0; i < locatie.length; i++){

    loc[locatie[i].location] = getKeyByValue(landcodes, locatie[i].location);

    land.push(locatie[i].location);
    landcount[loc[land[i]]] = locatie[i].count;


};
Object.assign(payments,landcount);




//     //initialize JQVMap

$(function(){
  $('#vmap').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_mill',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    series: {
      regions: [{
        values: payments,
        scale: ['#ffffff', '#414141'],
        normalizeFunction: 'linear',
        legend: {
            horizontal: true
        }

      }]
    },
    onRegionTipShow: function(e, el, code){

      el.html(el.html()+' (payments - '+payments[code]+')');
    }
  });
});
```

Code daterangepicker:

```
  $('#mapdate').daterangepicker({
    ranges   : {
      'Today'       : [moment(), moment()],
      'Yesterday'   : [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
      'Last 7 Days' : [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
      'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
      'This Month'  : [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
      'Last Month'  : [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    },
    startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
    endDate  : moment(),

  }, function (start, end) {
      var startRange = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      var endRange = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');


      $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

    

      $.ajax({
          url: "{{ route('ajaxRequest.post') }}",
          method: "POST",
          data:{start:startRange, end:endRange},

          success: function(data){

       
            startRange = getCookie('start');
           console.log(startRange);
           endRange = getCookie('end');
       
           console.log(endRange);
            refreshMap();



          },
      });
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: So which part of the map you want to "refresh"?  How do you initially generate the content of `#vmap`?

Comment: Edited in code of the map and daterangepicker

Answer (score 0):

is there a problem with removing all the content and then simply re-initializing the map?

```js
  $('#vmap').empty();

  $('#vmap').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_mill',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    series: {
      regions: [{
        values: payments,
        scale: ['#ffffff', '#414141'],
        normalizeFunction: 'linear',
        legend: {
            horizontal: true
        }

      }]
    },
    onRegionTipShow: function(e, el, code){

      el.html(el.html()+' (payments - '+payments[code]+')');
    }
  });
```

Comment: So what happened?

Comment: Same thing as before, map appears, when i try to change the daterangepicker it disappears.

Comment: If the initialization worked the first time i see no reason why it shouldn't work the second time. Any errors? Probably best you create a plunkr / stackblitz